# Redirecting merge of single file in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Is it possible to explicitly tell git during a merge that a certain file has been renamed or moved?

The background is that I have done a refactoring where a certain class has been generalized so that instead of having one class called "MyClass", I now have two classes "MyClassBase" and "MyClass". Almost all the logic in "MyClass" has been moved to "MyClassBase" but a virtual method has been added that "MyClass" implements.

"MyClassBase" and "MyClass" reside in separate files ("MyClassBase.cs" and "MyClass.cs"), and are the only classes in their respective files.

Now the problem is that when I do a merge, I get a lot of conflicts in "MyClass.cs" as there has been changes in that class on master. But If I were somehow able to tell git that the changes for the file "MyClass.cs" on master should really be merged into the file "MyClassBase.cs", then the merging would be almost trivial.

Comment: How would Git know which of the changes should be moved to another file and which should not?  Is it really a hassle to have to resolve a split file?

Comment: I'm not looking for a partial redirect for the file. I want all changes to "MyClass" on master to be merged into "MyClassBase" on my local branch.

Comment: I realized that my original description left some room for misinterpretation. The two classes reside in separate files and are the only classes in their respective files. I've updated the description and hope my intent is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the commit has been done already, you can add a dummy commit (add an empty line or even a comment line explaining the change) with an explaining commit message were you tell in details about the change.
The correct way to do such thing next time is to have that change as a single commit with a proper explanation.

Comment: I don't think I understand this. What change should be a single commit? My refactoring was a single commit, or actually two commits. One where I moved the file "MyClass.cs" to "MyClassBase.cs" and changed the class name, and one where I added the new "MyClass.cs" containing the class that extends "MyClassBase".

Comment: So it should have been a single commit that explains the change in the commit message. You can now add such commit with the explanation in the commit message

Comment: The commit messages did state the purpose, but how does this relate to the merge issues?

Comment: When you perform a merge you see a list of commits which the merge includes including its messages

Comment: Oh, is it the merge commit you are referring to? I haven't performed the merge yet, or at least I haven't committed the result. Git indicates (as expected) that there are conflicts in the file "MyClass.cs" that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Conflicts may indicate that beside the move of the code to the base class, there were other changes in the file itself. Git can't know that you moved it and the merge must be done manually

Answer (score 0):

I describe here what I ended up doing. It's not a very general solution, but it worked pretty well in my case.

When I did the refactoring I had committed my changes in two different stages. The first stage consisted of renaming "MyClass.cs" to "MyClassBase.cs" and modifying the name of the class in the new file. The second stage consisted of adding the new file "MyClass.cs" containing the class that extends "MyClassBase".

Now what I did was to go back to the changeset of the first stage and create a temporary merge branch. At that point it was trivial to merge with master because git would identify that the file had been moved. I then went back to my original branch and merged with the temporary branch. Since all the changes were now already in "MyClassBase.cs" on that branch, the merge became trivial.

In git commands, the flow would look something like this (where "mybranch" is the branch where I'm doing the change):

```
git mv MyClass.cs MyClassBase.cs
git commit -m "Renamed MyClass.cs to MyClassBase.cs"
git add MyClass.cs
git commit -m "Added MyClass.cs with subclass of MyClassBase."
git checkout HEAD^
git checkout -b tmpbranch
git merge origin/master
git checkout mybranch
git merge tmpbranch
```